# Кодировка текста в Ghost blog

Tags: mysql, node.js, ghost-blog

Я использую блогоплатформу Ghost как npm модуль. Когда пишу пост латинскими буквами - все нормально. Но, когда использую русский текст, происходят странные вещи. В самом блоге все отображается хорошо, но когда я захожу в базу(MySQL), я вижу там символы в непонятной кодировке - ÐÐ¾Ð²Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑ‚. Сервис определения кодировок говорит, что это ISO 8859-1(Latin-1). Но в config.js у меня прописана utf8 для базы и сама база в utf8. Из-за этой проблемы, я не могу использовать созданные посты нигде кроме блога, а хочу, например, на главной странице сайта выводить несколько последних записей. Но они выводятся теми же каракулями.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: посмотрите, как описана база данных, таблица (и столбцы) — что там про есть про *charset-ы*: `show create database имя;`, `show create table имя;`